# Display only anchors

Tags: greasemonkey, anchor

Could you advise me with writing a greasemonkey script displaying only anchors () in a web page and deleting everything else?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will wipe out everything but a list of the href's from links (added line breaks for clarity):

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll ("a");

//--- Build up new body, that will just display hrefs.
var newPageStr  = "";
for (var J=0, L=links.length;  J < L;  ++J) {

    //--- Skip links with empty href's.
    var href    = links[J].href;
    if ( /\w/.test (href) ) {
        newPageStr += '<a href="' + href + '">' + href + '</a><br>';
    }
}

//--- Replace everything on the page with the link list.
document.close ();
document.open ();
document.write (newPageStr);
document.close ();
```

---

### Update:

Since `document.write()` seems to flake in the GM environment, here's a DOM-based alternative:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll ("a");

//--- Build up new body, that will just display hrefs.
var newPageStr  = "";
for (var J=0, L=links.length;  J < L;  ++J) {

    //--- Skip links with empty href's.
    var href    = links[J].href;
    if ( /\w/.test (href) ) {
        newPageStr += '<a href="' + href + '">' + href + '</a><br>';
    }
}

//--- Erase everything from the page's body:
var b           = document.body;
var p           = b.parentNode;
p.removeChild (b);

//--- Add our new link list.
var newB        = document.createElement ("BODY");
newB.innerHTML  = newPageStr;
p.appendChild (newB);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested this snippet but it does not change the page at all (seems strange to me), but the script runs, it prints my alert message.

Comment: I tested it and it works perfectly in FF8 and GM. Your page may use AJAX or frames, etc. **Link to the target page** and we'll see what's going on.

Comment: There seems to be problem with `document.write()`. When I call only `document.write("hello")` it writes nothing. But your code looks credible.

Comment: `document.write("hello")` should normally work.  See my updated code which may solve some edge cases.  If it still doesn't work on *your* page (it works in all my tests) link to that page.

Comment: I created [new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539623/document-write-wont-show-the-text-on-the-web-page) question. Updated code didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    if (tags[i].tagName != 'A') {
        tags[i].style.color = 'transparent';
        tags[i].style.background = 'none';
        tags[i].style.border = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but this does not work. Shows more things than only hrefs.