# document.write won't show the text on the web page

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

When I run this simple `greasemonkey` script

```
alert("hello");
alert(document.location);
document.write("hello");
alert("hello");
```

Only the first two statements work, the third and fourth statement do nothing.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: They seem to work fine for me are Do you get any javascript errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `document.write()` only works intermittently from Greasemonkey -- maybe due to the sandbox.

I haven't found a foolproof recipe for duplicating the issue yet.

However, the DOM-based approach always seems to work.  Use this code:

```
//--- Erase everything from the page's body:
var b           = document.body;
var p           = b.parentNode;
p.removeChild (b);


//--- Add our new text or HTML.
var newB        = document.createElement ("BODY");
newB.innerHTML  = "Hello";
p.appendChild (newB);
```

PS: I updated my other answer as well.

Comment: This works, but I would like to solve the issue with `greasemonkey`. In firebug console works the code from the question without problems.

Comment: This does solve the issue with GM.  If you want `document.write()` to work reliably from GM, that may not be possible any time soon.  The DOM-based approach accomplishes your higher objective.

Comment: You're write. So it seems that `document.write()` is better to avoid in `greasemonkey`. Thanks.

Comment: Most JS codemeisters warn against `document.write()` on general principles.  I was a fool to ever suggest it, even if it initially worked in my tests and seemed like an easy approach.